# Erkennung einer alten Handschrift

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

Ich habe eine Kopie eines Manuskripts aus dem 18 Jahrhundert. Es handelt sich um [die Geburtstagskantate für Prinzessin Ulrike](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulrike_Sophie_zu_Mecklenburg#cite_note-2) einschließlich des Textes.

[image: Geburtstagskantate Prinzessin Ulrike]

Die Kopie ist nicht besonders gut. Die Handschrift ist teilweise schwer zu lesen. Einige Buchstaben kann ich [hier](http://www.suetterlinschrift.de/Lese/Sutterlin0.htm) auch nicht finden. Was ist eine gute Möglichkeit, diesen alten deutschen Text zu entziffern?

- [Seite 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYDnz.png)
- [Seite 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Ecn.png)

Comment: etwas offtopic, da auf den musikalischen Teil bezogen, aber vielleicht trotzdem nützlich: es gibt einen [ziemlich genialen Musik-NGram-Viewer](http://www.peachnote.com/), den man mit ein paar der Noten füttern könnte. Wäre spannend, zu sehen, ob man evtl. auch so das Werk identifizieren kann. [Hier](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/3737/679) hatte der Versuch zumindest Erfolg...

Comment: Danke, aber die Noten liegen vor. Die brauchen nur noch mit Lilypond in eine lesbare Form gebracht werden.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Es handelt sich um eine bereits im 18. Jahrhundert gebräuchliche [Kurrentschrift](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Kurrentschrift). Im verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel findet sich auch eine Alphabettafel, mit deren Hilfe man einzelne Buchstaben zuordnen kann.

Von den ersten beiden Zeilen kann ich folgendes entziffern:

> So schön sang in der ... (Schäfer?) Welt der redliche ... (Liron?), als Luna durch die Sternen irrte, die Nymphen hörten den Gesang

Hier noch drei weitere Verweise mit Beispielen und Schreib- und Leseübungen, die vielleicht von Interesse sind:

- [Kurrent](http://www.kurrent.de/index.htm)
- [Freunde der deutschen Kurrentschrift](http://www.deutsche-kurrentschrift.de/)
- [Geschichte Online](http://gonline.univie.ac.at/htdocs/site/browse.php?a=2255&arttyp=k)

Comment: Ja, es ist wohl eine Kurrentschrift. Ich würde gerne eine Schriftprobe bereitstellen. Jede gescannte Seite ist aber in einer ca. 33 MByte großen Datei. Das will ich niemandem antun.

Comment: @harper Lade die Daten doch auf einem Filehoster wie [Dropbox](http://db.tt/Alrb7nj) hoch und verlinke das dann hier.

Comment: Nun, wer sich 33 MByte pro Datei antun will, kann ja mal hier reingucken:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/82876780/IMG_0021.bmp
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/82876780/IMG_0022.bmp 
Besonders unklar: 1./2. Zeile (IMG21) und die letzten zwei Zeilen (IMG22)

Comment: Wie machst Du die Datei so klein? Ich würde auch noch andere Zeilen einbauen?

Answer (score 7):

Zusätzlich zu Takkats Antwort empfehle ich, Stück für Stück vorzugehen, und den bisher entzifferten Inhalt zu beachten. Schreib Dir das, was Du erkennen kannst, als Lückentext auf. Wenn Du in einem Satz ein oder zwei Wörter nicht lesen kannst, überlege, was grammatikalisch und thematisch passen könnte. Wenn Du ein Zeilenende entziffert hast, reimt sich das zweite vielleicht darauf.

Comment: +1 für den Lückentext, so mache ich das auch (sogar bei Handschriften aus dem 21. Jahrhundert) :)

Comment: Ja, der Lückentext hat geholfen. Auch das zunächst sinnlos (erscheinende) simple Aneinanderereihen von erkannten Buchstaben hilft in ähnlicher Weise.

Answer (score 4):

**Seite 1:**

So schön, sang in der Schäfer Welt der redliche Ei=

ron, als Luna durch die Sternen irrte, die Nymphen hörten den Ge=

sang, der durch den Wald bis zum Olimpus drang. Voll Zuversicht

daß frommer Schäfer unentweyhte Pflicht, die Götter die den Hain be=

wohnen mit Beyfall segnen und belohnen, sang er, es neigten sich die

Wipfel hoher Bäume, der Schäfer Wunsch das Glück der guten

Träume der Luna und den Göttern vor. Die Götter

**Seite 2:**

segneten den redlichen Eiron, wer segnet uns, wenn wir so redlich

flehn (?) ! Zwar Luna, steigt aus unsren nächtlich frohen Chor kein (?) Lied zu

dir empor. Die Vorsicht bester Menschen Güter

dir Herr des Tages und der Nacht, dir eintziger Geber al - ler Güter, dir sey Danck und Ge=

beth - gebracht, dir  eintziger Geber al - ler Güter, dir sey Danck und Gebet gebracht.

Geselle du der Mahanaim Wachen Ulrikens sanften Schlummer bey, laß morgen

sie vergnügt erwachen, daß ihr Geburtstag uns ein Fest der Freude sey.

*Bemerkung:*

Die Worte "Ulrikens" und "Geburtstag" scheinen mit einer anderen Feder als der Rest des Textes geschrieben zu sein - vielleicht wurden sie nachträglich an Leerstellen eingefügt.

Comment: +1. Kleine Dittographie in Deiner Transkription Z. 6: die / **die** Wipfel.

Comment: @marquinho Danke, ist korrigiert!